# Is it possible to rectify two linearly independent vectors by the same diffeomorphism to the first two unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we are given two vector fields $V_1$ and $V_2$ defined on $\mathbb R^n$ such that
the vectors $V_1(x)$ and $V_2(x)$ are linearly independent for each $x$. Is is possible
to find a diffeomorphism $\phi$ from a neighborhood $V$ of 0 to a neighborhood $U$
of 0 such that ($D_{\phi_x}(V_1(x)),D_{\phi_x}(V_2(x)) = (e_1, e_2)$
for each $x$ in $V$? Here $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the first two unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice theorem from differential geometry. Such a diffeomorphism around $0$ will exist if and only if the Lie bracket $[V_1,V_2]=0$.

Comment: Can you give the name of the theorem and a possible source?

Comment: I don't think it has a name. It's Theorem 14 from Chapter 5 of Spivak's _A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry_, V1, 3rd Edition. It's on page 158.